# Could not find a declaration file for module 'bson'

Tags: node.js, bson

I did a `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache verify && npm install && npm run start` and now my console is complaining about

> node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:46:78 - error TS7016: Could not
> find a declaration file for module 'bson'.
> '/Users/microurb/Projects/backend/node_modules/bson/index.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/bson` if
> it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bson';`
>
> 46 import { Binary, Decimal128, Double, Int32, Long, ObjectId,
> Timestamp } from "bson";

I did not get this error at all before, how did this error come up just because of running the above?

I tried running `npm i --save-dev @types/bson`, but that did not solve that.

Comment: Complaining "about" or complaining _exactly_? What is the _exact_ error you get? (and not just the first line, the whole error).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, pasted the full error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by just adding `// @ts-ignore` above:

`import { Binary, Decimal128, Double, Int32, Long, ObjectId, Timestamp } from "bson";`

inside the `@types/mongodb` package.

Comment: Tell us how to do this in production

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by installing bson as well

`npm i --save-dev bson`

It doesn't appear to be included in mongo deps for some reason

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).